# Magento2 routeId_controller_action make landing page

Tags: blocks, home, page

I make a `Block` in my custom module and there a logic exist . I have also make `controller ,xml file(for define block class and template file) ,template` 
in Controller nothing custom code exist just `pagefactory` exist in execute method.
Now Path is `domain.com\routerid\controller\action`

But I need   `domain.com`

How can i make `domain.com\routerid\controller\action` on `landing page` ???

Comment: So when someone browse domain.com, should load domain.com\routerid\controller\action?

Comment: Yes i want to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using router, the following example will forward home request to contact page, change that line. So when you browse home page, that will display contact page.

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">SR\MagentoCommunity\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Controller/Router.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory;

class Router implements RouterInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ActionFactory
     */
    private $actionFactory;

    /**
     * Router constructor.
     *
     * @param ActionFactory $actionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ActionFactory $actionFactory
    ) {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface|null
     */
    public function match(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        if (!$identifier && !$request->getControllerName()) {
            $request->setModuleName('contact')->setControllerName('index')->setActionName('index');
            $request->setAlias(\Magento\Framework\Url::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS, 'contact');
            $request->setDispatched(true);
            return $this->actionFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward::class);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir ? 
$request->setModuleName('contact')->setControllerName('index')->setActionName('index');

Sir setModuleName('contact') ? mean i define custom module name like setModuleName('VendorName_moduleName')?

Comment: No, router_id from routes.xml

Comment: No, Sir it not work for me . 
No effect on `www.domain.com` it same as before this code

Comment: Not sure how you check. Can you upload your sample module somewhere?

Comment: Yes ? in chat ?

Comment: not sure, I want to check your module

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93577/discussion-between-hafiz-umer-and-sohel-rana).

Comment: it work perfect!